# Wordpress Coding Critical Error - Asgaros Forum Reactions to Posts

Tags: wordpress, forum

The plugin author used this code to show off the new reactions to forum posts which works perfect,

```
function add_reactions($reactions) {
  $reactions['heart'] = array(
    'icon' => 'fas fa-heart',
    'screen_reader_text' => __('Click for heart.', 'asgaros-forum')
  );
  return $reactions;
}
add_filter('asgarosforum_reactions', 'add_reactions');
```

However when I try adding multiple reactions it causes a critical error, obviously I'm doing something wrong...

```
function add_reactions($reactions) {
$reactions['amar'] = array(
'icon' => 'fas fa-heart',
'screen_reader_text' => __('Amar', 'asgaros-forum')
);
return $reactions;
}

function add_reactions($reactions) {
$reactions['divertido'] = array(
'icon' => 'fas fa-laugh',
'screen_reader_text' => __('Divertido', 'asgaros-forum')
);
return $reactions;
}

function add_reactions($reactions) {
$reactions['triste'] = array(
'icon' => 'fas fa-sad-tear',
'screen_reader_text' => __('Triste', 'asgaros-forum')
);
return $reactions;
}

function add_reactions($reactions) {
$reactions['enojado'] = array(
'icon' => 'fas fa-angry',
'screen_reader_text' => __('Enojado', 'asgaros-forum')
);
return $reactions;
}

function add_reactions($reactions) {
$reactions['sorprendido'] = array(
'icon' => 'fas fa-surprise',
'screen_reader_text' => __('Sorprendido', 'asgaros-forum')
);
return $reactions;
}

function add_reactions($reactions) {
$reactions['genialidad'] = array(
'icon' => 'fas fa-fire',
'screen_reader_text' => __('Genialidad', 'asgaros-forum')
);
return $reactions;
}

function add_reactions($reactions) {
$reactions['elegante'] = array(
'icon' => 'fas fa-lightbulb',
'screen_reader_text' => __('Elegante', 'asgaros-forum')
);
return $reactions;
}

add_filter('asgarosforum_reactions', 'add_reactions');
```

I've tried everything I know, still get critical errors on frontend wordpress site.

Comment: I've also tried adding `add_filter('asgarosforum_reactions', 'add_reactions');` behind each reaction but still critical error on wordpress.

Comment: You cannot declare `add_reactions` same functions multple times.

Comment: What is the correct code then? Nothing works for me..

Comment: you should declare this function only one time `add_reactions `

Comment: "it causes a critical error" - can you share the full and exact error message, along with your attempts to resole the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use like this

```
function add_reactions($reactions) {
    $reactions['amar'] = array(
        'icon' => 'fas fa-heart',
        'screen_reader_text' => __('Amar', 'asgaros-forum')
    );
    $reactions['divertido'] = array(
        'icon' => 'fas fa-laugh',
        'screen_reader_text' => __('Divertido', 'asgaros-forum')
    );
    $reactions['triste'] = array(
        'icon' => 'fas fa-sad-tear',
        'screen_reader_text' => __('Triste', 'asgaros-forum')
    );
    $reactions['enojado'] = array(
        'icon' => 'fas fa-angry',
        'screen_reader_text' => __('Enojado', 'asgaros-forum')
    );
    $reactions['sorprendido'] = array(
        'icon' => 'fas fa-surprise',
        'screen_reader_text' => __('Sorprendido', 'asgaros-forum')
    );
    $reactions['genialidad'] = array(
        'icon' => 'fas fa-fire',
        'screen_reader_text' => __('Genialidad', 'asgaros-forum')
    );
    $reactions['elegante'] = array(
        'icon' => 'fas fa-lightbulb',
        'screen_reader_text' => __('Elegante', 'asgaros-forum')
    );
    return $reactions;
}


add_filter('asgarosforum_reactions', 'add_reactions');
```

Comment: That worked!!!! Thank you so much @Vel `return $reactions;` only needed this one time. Thank you!